# How do I run selected SQL queries with variables included?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to be able to run a snippet of my SQL query by selecting it and pressing `F5`. Issue is, if that selection contains a variable name I get an error: `Must declare the scalar variable "@variableName".`. Is there anyway to resolve this? I want `variableName` to be the value it would otherwise be had I run the whole statement at that moment in time that I've selected...

Sample of full code:

```
DECLARE @cat INT;

SET @cat = 2;

SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE ColumnName = @cat;
```

Sample of my selection that I want to run without including declaration/set lines:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE ColumnName = @cat;
```

Probably not possible but I figured it'd be worth a shot.

P.S. I'm a SQL noobie so if I'm missing something obvious let me know!

Comment: Post the query.. When variable is used in query, then `declare` statement should be part of execution else you will get that error...

Comment: @Pரதீப் I can't for confidentiality reasons, sorry. I could replace names and stuff but the code is quite long and that would take forever.. uh I could try an example 1 sec.

Comment: Just include the code which defines/initializes the variable before and with the actual query.  Then F5 the whole thing together.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That code is at the top of the page and my snippet is in the middle. So I can't highlight all of that together without including unwanted content in-between

Comment: Got it.  Not sure I have a clever workaround.

Comment: I find the easiest way to do this is to add comments in relevant places with the variable declarations. e.g. if i have `declare @cat INT = 69;` up the top then an extremely long code block then, for example, `select * from table where columnName = @cat;` i'll have a comment `--declare @cat INT = 69;` on a line above the select statement so I can readily run that select at any time. Outside of this, I don't believe there's any real way to do what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand where you are coming from. This is a snippet in a long procedure or something and naturally you want to keep the declarations at the top, which I agree with. In this case, when you are testing, the only real way to circumvent this is to re-declare it and set it at the top of your snippet. Then, when you are running the entire batch of code just comment out this line. Otherwise you'd have to wrap the snippet in a try / catch block to try and catch compile errors which is tricky.

Also, this is usually how I've seen people put a select * from someWorkTable to test results along the way. Then it's commented out when the batch is ran.

Answer (score 0):

Left click on table name, right click design and you are able to view the datatype of the column name. 
if it is nvarchar..

```
DECLARE @cat INT;
SET @cat = 2;
Convert(varchar, @cat)

SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE ColumnName = @cat;
```

OR

directly declare

```
DECLARE @Cat VARCHAR(3)
SET @cat = '2'
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE ColumnName = @cat;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate your variable as declared in a select query with an alias result.  Then you can just use alias.column as part of your join...

```
SELECT 
      TN.* 
   FROM 
      ( select '2' as TmpColumn ) tmpAlias
         JOIN TableName TN
            on tmpAlias.TmpColumn = TN.ColumnName
```

this way, no "scalar" variable is required, but not as practical as a simple parameterized query using a direct WHERE clause.  Additionally, you could use the alias.column throughout in case you had other tables relations, etc or even additional "variables" you wanted to apply in your query.